# How do I SELECT my content and all the tags that go with it?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've tried very hard to have a normalized database and currently have three tables like so -

1. content (c)
2. content_tags (ct)
3. tags (t)

What I'm trying to do here is select some rows and return them with all the tags that are associated with it. At the moment, it only returns one tag for some reason.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
   SELECT *, 
          GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag) AS tags
     FROM content AS c 
LEFT JOIN category AS ca ON c.cid = ca.cid 
LEFT JOIN contenttags AS ct ON c.smid = ct.smid 
LEFT JOIN tags AS t ON ct.tid = t.tid 
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON c.uid = u.uid
    WHERE (t.tag IN ('tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3'))
 GROUP BY c.smid
```

It returns something like this:

- cid
- content
- url
- tag (but only one instead of multiple)

Comment: "One tag", as in only one tag -- or duplicate `CONTENT` records with different tags?  I'd believe you're seeing the former rather than the latter, which means you need to check your data (start from the tags table, and add joins...) to see what is causing tags to "disappear".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean to find all contents and all their tags, where at least one of their tag is in `$tagArray` ?

```
   SELECT c.*, ca.*, u.*, 
          GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag) AS tags
     FROM content AS c 
LEFT JOIN category AS ca ON c.cid = ca.cid 
     JOIN contenttags AS ct ON c.smid = ct.smid 
     JOIN tags AS t ON ct.tid = t.tid 
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON c.uid = u.uid
    WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT *
                   FROM contenttags ct2
                     JOIN tag t2
                       ON t2.tid = ct2.tid
                   WHERE ct2.smid = c.smid
                     AND ct2.tag IN ('$tagArray')
                 )
 GROUP BY c.smid
```

And those `LEFT JOIN` can be probably turned into inner `JOIN`s, too, without losing any results. Try it. Unless `category.cid` or `category.uid` fields can have `NULL` values. In that case, keep the related `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: I tried playing around with the code above but to no success. But when you say "find all contents and all their tags, where at least of their  tag is in $tagArray" is correct. Before I normalized the database, this was easy to accomplish as the tags were just in "tag1,tag2,tag3" fashion

Comment: @allanminium: Sorry, it was not doing what it was supposed to do. See the edit.

Answer (score 2):

This is your problem.

```
WHERE (t.tag IN ('$tagArray'))
```

Consider the following two expression do different things:

```
WHERE (t.tag IN (1,2,3,4))
WHERE (t.tag IN ('1,2,3,4'))
```

The quoted string, in spite of appearing to be a list of multiple integers, is in fact a single value.  In an integer context, MySQL reads the leading digits ('1' in this case) and ignores anything following once it finds a non-digit.

---

What I'm saying is that the quotes on either side of your query are confusing.  Is the value of $tagArray literally `tag1','tag2','tag3`?  Or is it `'tag1','tag2','tag3'`?

In general, troubleshoot SQL by looking at SQL, not by looking at PHP code that is producing SQL.  And please show the final SQL query in your question, don't make us guess what the value of $tagArray is.

---

PS: This is probably not related to your question, but you're using LEFT JOIN where you need INNER JOIN.

Comment: The $tagArray variable, when it goes into MySQL looks like this - "WHERE (t.tag IN ('tag1',  'tag2',  'tag3'))" and seems to pick up all the correct rows that I require. But if I only had "tag1" in there, it wouldn't tell me there is also a "tag2" and a "tag3"

Comment: Okay, I've changed the value of $tagArray to what the variable should look like. My apologies about the confusion! I'll try out the INNER JOIN in a little bit. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to do a second join on the tags table--one for the WHERE clause, and one to return all related results.  Untested, but try this:

```
SELECT c.*,t2.*,ca.*,ct.*,u.* GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag) AS tags
FROM content AS c
LEFT JOIN category AS ca ON c.cid = ca.cid
LEFT JOIN contenttags AS ct ON c.smid = ct.smid
LEFT JOIN tags AS t2 ON ct.tid = t2.tid
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON c.uid = u.uid
JOIN tags AS t ON ct.tid = t.tid
WHERE (t.tag IN ('$tagArray'))
GROUP BY c.smid
```

This will return a separate row for every related tag, so you'll have to merge those results in your client code, or perhaps use [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) if you want all the tags on a single row (as an array)

Comment: I think I see where you're trying to go with it. MySQL returns me this error message though :(

#1054 - Unknown column 'ct.tid' in 'on clause'

It seems that "ct" isn't declared yet as it is lower down

Comment: Hopefully reordering the joins will help with that--I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for that! I also tried reordering it myself but to no avail :(

I also tried going about it differently but with your idea of having a second join on the tag table like so - "SELECT c.smid, c.material, GROUP_CONCAT( t.tag ) 
FROM content AS c
LEFT JOIN contenttags AS ct ON ct.smid = c.smid
LEFT JOIN tags AS t ON t.tid = ct.tid
LEFT JOIN tags AS t2 ON t2.tid = ct.tid
WHERE (
t2.tag
IN (
'tag1'
)
)
GROUP BY c.smid" but it still only returns the "tag1" tag and no other tags with it